# Bootstrap responsive panel with thumbnails and custom content, not exactly responding as expected

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm in a coding Boot camp, been coding for a little over 1.5 months. For one of my assignments, I was to create a mobile responsive portfolio using Bootstrap.  The directions clearly stated not to use media queries, as the queries are under the hood on of my TAs told me.  Inasmuch as I'm not allowed to implement explicit use of queries, I seem to be stumped.  I already turned the assignment is, but dont want to skim ovedr the solution - if there is one.  Here is my html:

---

```
 <div class="container" id="page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="panel" id="main-section">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 id="headings">Portfolio</h4>
                            <div class="row" id="box-search">
                             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                        <img src="hangman.jpg" class="image-responsive" id="images-left">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p style="background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff" id="text-box">Hangman</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                        <img src="rpg.jpg" class="image-responsive" id="images-right">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p style="background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff">Role Player Game</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="box-search">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                        <img src="trivia.jpg" class="image-responsive" id="images-left">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p style="background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff"`enter code here`>Trivia</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                        <img src="rutgers.jpg" class="image-responsive" id="images-right">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p style="background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff" id="text-box">Rutgers Info Widget</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="box-search">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                                        <img src="rps.jpg " class="image-responsive " id="images-left">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p  style="background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff;" id="text-box">Rock Paper Scissors</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

---

and the css:

```
  .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 0px;
   width: 190px;
   text-align: center;

}
#images-left,
#images-right  {
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;

}

/*portfolio styling*/
#main-section-port  {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 640px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

and here is a link to the actual website if you'd like to see: afflatus480.github.io

Again, I already submitted the work, so no need to rush.  But any help will be appreciated nonetheless. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: When I resize the screen to, say, 640px the .caption text boxes(used for image labels - z-index 1) dont seem to respond with the images, some spanning the entire panel, overlapping adjacent image.

Comment: @toby - My question: Is there a way to adhere text boxes to images in bootstrap, both responding to viewport changes together as one. **without expicit use of media queries?***

Comment: You're using `.thumbnail` to position both the caption and img. Add a div around the image, then set that div to `position: relative`, that div will then get it's size from the image.

Comment: That kinda helped a little. Thanks @Toby. Perhaps the direction not to use Media Queries is or was to show how much I really need them lol. Thank you, again.

Comment: This is less about media queries, and more about thinking about content sizing/positioning. For example, a caption with two words will likely never overflow and cause issues, whereas a caption with eight words will almost always cause problems in a responsive layout.

Comment: So in the real-world when I have more creative freedom, perhaps choose caption lengths that size and resize properly?  Again, I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: lol, there will only ever be less creative freedom in the real world. It's something you get used to thinking about when working with front end development.

Comment: Ohhhh, yeah, guess I overlooked the fact that in lieu of teachers and TAs there will be paying clients with loads of creativity lol